# How can received and clear an array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to look for a number with maximum divisors in a range of 1 - 10000.

I succeeded, but then I wish to verify if there exist more than two max divisors and print them out. My array is really the problem. How can I clear an array and assign a new integer to it in an if else if statement?

Here is what I have tried:

```
function countDivisors(){

    $input = 10000;
     $maxNumOfDiv = -1;
     $intWMaxDivs = -1;
    $curNumOfDiv = 0;
    $arr = array();

     for($i=1; $i <= $input; $i++) {
         $curNumOfDiv = 0;
         for ($j = 1; $j < $i; $j++){
             
            if ($i % $j == 0)
               
                $curNumOfDiv++;
         }

         if($curNumOfDiv = $maxNumOfDiv){
             $arr[] = $i;
               $intWMaxDivs = $i;
              $maxNumOfDiv = $curNumOfDiv;
         } else if($curNumOfDiv > $maxNumOfDiv){
            
             $arr = array();
             $arr[] = $intWMaxDivs
              
             $maxNumOfDiv = $curNumOfDiv;
         }
         
     }
    
     for ($i; $i < count($arr); $i++){
         echo $arr[$i]['intWMaxDivs'];
         echo $arr[$i]['maxNumOfDiv'];
     }
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to show the biggest divisor and the amount of divisors for all numbers in a range from 1-10000?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding this question a little. If you are looking for a single number with maximum number of dividers, it should be something like this.

```
<?php

$max_num=10000;
$start_num=1;
$max_divs=-1;
$max_number=-1;
$numbers=array();

$max_divs_arr=array();


for($i=$start_num;$i<=$max_num;$i++)
{

        $divs=0;
        $div_array=array();
        for($j=$start_num;$j<=$i;$j++)
        {
                if($i%$j==0)
                {
                        $divs++;
                        $div_array[]=$j;
                }
        }



        if($divs==$max_divs)
        $max_divs_arr[$i]=$div_array;

        if($divs>$max_divs)
        {
                $max_divs_arr=array();
                $max_divs=$divs;
                $max_divs_arr[$i]=$div_array;
        }


}



foreach($max_divs_arr as $number=>$divisors)
echo "\nNumber with most divisors is $number\nIt has $max_divs divisors\nThose divisors are:".implode(',',$divisors);
```

Comment: well, i got the single number with most divisor. but then i was thinking that they may exist two of these numbers having same number of divisors. again, what if i wish to see all numbers and the number of divisor for each of these numbers.

Comment: ah, i see. in that case all you need is to create another case for when number of divisors is equal to what you already have. updating answer now

Answer (score 0):

```
$div = [];

$maxDivKey = false;
$maxDiv = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j < $i; $j++){
             
        if ($i % $j == 0){
            $div[$i][] = $i.'/'.$j.'='.$i/$j;
        }
        
        if($j == $i-1){
            $count = count($div[$i]);
            $div[$i]['count'] = $count;
            if($maxDiv < $count){
                $maxDiv = $count;
                $maxDivKey = $i;
            }
        }
    }
}


echo '<h1>Max divisors:</h1>';
print_r($div[$maxDivKey]);
//print_r($div);
```